# Need some way to cast object from 3rd party DLL to object from local class

Tags: asp.net, .net, oop, casting, type-conversion

Background: in my website, a 3rd party HTTP Module builds a collection of objects in the HttpRuntime Cache. In my web application project, I need to examine these objects in the Cache and take various actions if an object with a particular property value is found.

So, I am looping through the cache collection, trying to cast each object to an instance of a local class (which is identical to the design of the 3rd party class).

(I know I could create a reference to the 3rd party assembly, but the assembly might not be installed, so I am try to create a more robust method).

However, the cast doesn't work. ASP.NET knows that the original object originates from a different assembly. This is the exception:

> [A]3rdParty.HttpModule.CachedRequest cannot be cast to
>   [B]3rdParty.HttpModule.CachedRequest. Type A originates from
>   '3rdParty.HttpModule, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\61910352\63f5dc4f\assembly\dl3\710995cc\37f36a76_71e5cb01\3rdParty.HttpModule.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'MyCompany.MyWebsite, Version=1.4.0.1396,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at
>   location 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\61910352\63f5dc4f\assembly\dl3\8bfb9ba0\0c053836_8595cc01\MyCompany.MyWebsite.DLL'.

All I need to do is check the value of 1 string property in the object. Is there some (simple) way to do this? Even serializing the object to a string and parsing the string would be OK.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET is strong-typed, so no, you can't cast an object to something of a different type -- even if the memory layout happens to be identical, .NET knows they're different types.

To read a property of an object, without having a compile-type reference to its assembly, you need to use either Reflection, or `dynamic`. `dynamic` is probably simpler.

```
dynamic theObject = // get the object from the cache
DoSomethingWith(theObject.TheProperty);
```

Comment: Perfect. This (dynamic) is exactly what I needed and simple to implement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to repeat such steps in your application, I would recommand to use a Mapper.

[AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) would do what you want.

It will copy the content of the variables from an object, to the variables in another object (variables names need to match).
You can then work with a fully editable object (adding Interfaces, Inheritance etc), and then "map" it back to the original third-party object once you're done with it.